# Creating a tree like tasks with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to create an application that create tasks, and said tasks might create children tasks or eventually terminate.

This is failing as it says "Pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled"

Any help would be appreciated

```
import multiprocess as mp

import random
import time


def generate_weighted_random_task_list():
    num = random.choices([0, 1, 2, 3], weights=[70, 10, 10, 10], k=1)[0]

    if num == 0:
        return ["completed"]
    else:
        return [f"Task {i+1}" for i in range(num)]


class Task:
    def resolve_task(self, task):
        return generate_weighted_random_task_list()


class TaskNode:
    def __init__(self, task_key, goal):
        self.task_key = task_key
        self.goal = goal
        self.children = []

    def execute(self, pool):  # Pass the centralized pool as an argument
        agent = Task()
        sub_tasks = agent.resolve_task(self.goal)

        if sub_tasks == ["completed"]:
            return self.task_key + " finished"

        self.children = [
            TaskNode(self.task_key + "_" + str(i), sub_task)
            for i, sub_task in enumerate(sub_tasks)
        ]

        # Using the centralized pool instead of creating a new one
        results = pool.map(
            lambda child: child.execute(pool), self.children
        )  # Pass the pool down

        print(results)
        return [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]


with mp.Pool(processes=1) as pool:
    root_task = TaskNode("1", "Achieve Task")
    results = root_task.execute(pool)  # Starting the execution with the centralized pool
    print(results)
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but have you considered using [ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/walkthrough.html)? I think it would be better suited for your task.